# Simplify conventional foreach nested loop using linq & lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, nested-loops

(See my code snippet below) I want to find all items of coll1 that matched to items of coll2 (number of items of coll2 <= number of items of coll1) and put the query result in coll3. How to achieve it using linq and lambda expression?
Surely, I can simply copy coll2 to coll3 :-) but that is not my goal. I want to know the ways using linq and lambda to replace such conventional logic construct. Thank you in advance.

```
        var coll1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        var coll2 = new List<int>() { 2, 4 };
        var coll3 = new List<int>();
        foreach ( var selected in coll2 )
        {
            foreach ( var item in coll1 )
            {
                if ( selected == item )
                {
                    coll3.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx)

```
coll1.Intersect(coll2);
```

But this wont work as expected(see King King's comment)..You can instead do this

```
coll2.Where(x=>coll1.Any(y=>x==y));
```

Comment: This seems the best solution to me. +1

Comment: this won't work as expected: if `col2 = {1,2,3,4}`, `col1 = {2,2,4}`. This will return `{2,4}` while the result should be `{2,2,4}`?

Comment: @KingKing nice observation king..thanks to point it out..corrected the ans..:)

Comment: @Anirudh: it works for me like this: `coll3 = coll2.Where(x => coll1.Any(y => x == y)).ToList();` .. +1 still.

Answer (score 6):

```
coll3 = coll1.Where(i => coll2.Contains(i)).ToList();
```

**Update.** A little bit simpler, as suggested in comments:

```
coll3 = coll1.Where(coll2.Contains).ToList();
```

Comment: You can simplify that to: `var coll3 = coll1.Where(coll2.Contains).ToList();`

Answer (score 2):

As a first step, you can use a [where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) clause to make your code more readable :

```
    var coll1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    var coll2 = new List<int>() { 2, 4 };
    var coll3 = new List<int>();
    foreach (var selected in coll2)
    {
        coll3.AddRange(coll1.Where(item => selected == item));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Intersect: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx

```
var coll3 = coll1.Intersect(coll2)
```

Comment: it doesn't work as expected (see comment of King King to Anirudh's answer).

Answer (score 1):

You could do this; not sure if it's more readable tho!

```
var coll3 = (from selected in coll2
                from item in coll1
                where selected == item
                select item).ToList();
```

Comment: This exactly what resharper proposes too.

Comment: I wonder about the downvote. This code is correct, so why? Although it looks like some numpty has just downvoted all the answers here...

Comment: @Matthew Watson: who downvoted? strange. I am sure I give u +1 :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to directly assign the result to your list, you could add 'ForEach' to your Linq statement:

```
coll1.Where(i => coll2.Contains(i)).ToList().ForEach(i => coll3.Add(i));
```

**You might want to check for Distinct though**